# How do you extract all archives even with wrong extensions?

Tags: bash

I have to extract all archives in my current folder. What I'm doing only extracts all that are named correctly but the archives can have any messed up extension on them.

file.tar.gvz

or file.tar.potatogz

or file.sss.faz

```
  gunzip *.tar.gz >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
  echo $?
  echo "gzip"
  tar -xvf *.tar >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
  echo $?
  echo "tar"
  unzip '*.zip' >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
  echo $?
  echo "zip"
```

Edit: 
 The file command seems like the right way to go but I can't get it to work in a nested loop. when outside the directory loop it works fine.

```
for D in *; do
  if [ -d "${D}" ]; then
    cd $D
    bool=false
      for files in *
      do
        type=$( file -b $files | awk '{printf $1;}' )
        echo "next is type"
        echo $type
        done
       cd..
 done
```

Comment: can you test files for type gzip (`file` command) and then run gunzip only on those?

Comment: I tried using the file command but when I try to store the output into a variable I get 
"ERROR: cannot open" 
I take it this isn't right 
    type=$( file -b $files | awk '{print $1;}' )

Comment: You can just try to unzip * and the files which aren't zip files won't be unzipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The File command solved this.
My problems with file were solved with quotation marks.

```
  type=$( file -b "$j" | awk '{printf $1;}' )
```

Answer (score 1):

When gunzip reads from stdin, it doesn't know that the filename was wrong:

```
cat archive_with_wrong_name | gunzip -c
```

Or even easier...

```
gunzip -c <archive_with_wrong_name
```

Or even easier...

```
gzcat archive_with_wrong_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are real close. How about something like this?

```
for D in *; do
    if [ -d "${D}" ]; then
        cd $D
        for file in *; do
            type="$( file -b "$file" | awk '{print $1}' )"
            case "$type" in
                'gzip' ) gunzip $file; continue ;;
                'zip' ) unzip $file; continue ;;
                'tar' ) tar xzf $file; continue ;;
                '*' ) continue ;;
            esac
        done
        cd ..
    fi           
done
```